# Exception in async try-catch

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, azure-storage

Somehow I end up with the rare situation that an id is returned, but the blob hasn't been saved. Is there anything I'm missing in below code regarding C# 6 async in catch-statements or maybe an odd bug in the Azure libraries?

```
private async Task<string> Save(Stream stream)
{
    var id = Guid.NewGuid();
    var blob = ...;

    try
    {
        await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
    }
    catch
    {
        if (await blob.ExistsAsync())
        {
            await blob.DeleteAsync();
        }
        throw;
    }

    return id;
}
```

Comment: Not a solution, but note there is a more atomic [DeleteIfExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.deleteifexists(v=azure.10).aspx) API call, which should also be less I/O.

Comment: Are you sure you are catching an exception? Is it possible `blob.UploadFromStreamAsync` didn't throw an exception, but also didn't do what you expect?

Comment: @Kobi yes, that's what I fear. But I would expect the library to throw if the upload wasn't successful. It's also possible the file is corrupted, but I would expect to still get the blob with binary data. Testing for existence after the upload would be an option, but it masks an underlying issue, no?

Comment: @Benjamin can you confirm if the file is being uploaded correctly or not? For example, by comparing the original to the uploaded copy using a tool like VBinDiff.

Comment: @john I don't have the original. This happened on 12 out of 2.5 million files and only in the last week. No way to recover the original. Patching nugets now :|

Comment: Perhaps as a way of confirming the issue, you could call `blob.FetchAttributesAsync()` after upload and then compare a local MD5 hash to the `blob.Properties.ContentMD5` value. Obviously this would probably add a fair bit of processing time and depends if your stream is a 1-time read or not.

Comment: how about displaying the exception you get in the catch to identify the actual exception encountered instead of throwing again in the catch.

Comment: @SaherAhwal There is centralized logging for all exceptions. In case of async issues this could be lost, e.g. return and kill thread before logging is completed. There are no exceptions logged for this issue